# Formatting Text in the googlesheet cell using a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that has formatted text in a cell. Some of the text has color and is bold. I use a google script to add new content in the cell. When I run the script, the new content is added but the formatting of the old content is removed.

1) How can I keep the formatting of the old content when executing my script.
2) I want to make the new content bold and colored. How can I format the newcontent that is added to the cell?

Here is the content of my cell before executing the script[image]

Here is my script:

```
  function CreateIssue() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  var oldContent = cell.getValue();
  var newContent ='Group:\n\nDescription:\n\nExpected Results:\n\nActual Results:\n\nTest 
  Results:\n\nTest Data:';
  var space = " ";
  cell.setValue(newContent + space + oldContent);
```

Here is the content of my cell after executing the script[image]

As you can see, the formatting was cleared for the old content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- You want to add the text to the top of text in the cell and put it to the cell.
- In this case, you want to keep the text style of the original text.
- You want to change the text style of the added text to "bold" and "ForegroundColor".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as justo one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

When the value is put using `setValue`, it seems that the text style is cleared. This might be the specification. So in this case, in order to set the text style, I used Class TextStyleBuilder and Class RichTextValueBuilder. The flow of this modified script is as follows.

Flow:

1. Retrieve the cell range.
2. Create the text style of additional texts which are `newContent` and `space`.
3. Retrieve the text style of the original texts which is `oldContent`.
4. Create new RichTextValueBuilder.
5. Set new texts to RichTextValueBuilder.
6. Set the text style to RichTextValueBuilder.
7. Put RichTextValueBuilder to the cell.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows. Please select a cell including `oldContent` and run the script. By this, `newContent` and `space` are added to `oldContent`, and the text styles are set.

```
function CreateIssue() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  var oldContent = cell.getValue();
  var newContent = 'Group:\n\nDescription:\n\nExpected Results:\n\nActual Results:\n\nTest Results:\n\nTest Data:';
  var space = " ";

  // I added below script.
  var newStyles = [{
    start: 0,
    end: newContent.length,
    style: SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).setForegroundColor("green").build()
  }];
  var richTextValue = cell.getRichTextValue();
  var offset = newContent.length + space.length;
  var oldContent = richTextValue.getText();
  if (oldContent.length > 0) {
    richTextValue.getRuns().forEach(function(e) {
      newStyles.push({
        start: offset + e.getStartIndex(),
        end: offset + e.getEndIndex(),
        style: e.getTextStyle()
      });
    });
  }
  var richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(newContent + space + oldContent);
  newStyles.forEach(function(e) {richText.setTextStyle(e.start, e.end, e.style)});
  cell.setRichTextValue(richText.build());
}
```

- In above script, the additional text is put as the bold and green color. About this, when you want to change the color, please modify it.

#### Result:

When `var newContent = "foo";` is set and select a cell including the text of "bar" which has the text style and run the above script, the following result can be obtained.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

The original text style is kept and the additional text has the text style.

#### References:

- [Class TextStyleBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-style-builder)
- [Class RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Really appreciate the working code sample with example use illustrated. My use case is entirely different, but this sample code with example worked just as described and gave me a place to start.

Comment: @Tony M Thank you for your comment. I'm glad this answer is useful for you. Thank you, too.