# Change text inside cells to a different color

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

To be clear, I want to change the color of SOME text inside the cell. Not change the entire cell's font color.

I want to loop down a column and change all STRIKETHROUGH text inside cells to a different color (say "grey" as an example").

[image]

My code below is my failed attempt.

```
function changeUnderlineColor() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Activity Log"); // Get the active sheet
  var column = ss.getRangeByName("toDos").getColumn(); // Set the column number where you want to apply the formatting
  var range = sheet.getRange(3, column, sheet.getLastRow(), 1); // Get the range of the column
  var values = range.getValues(); // Get the values of the range

  var redColor = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("#ff0000").build();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var cell = range.getCell(i + 1, 1); // Get the cell in the current row
    var richTextValue = cell.getRichTextValue(); // Get the rich text value of the cell
    Logger.log(richTextValue)
    var richText = richTextValue.getRuns(); // Get the rich text runs in the cell
    
    for (var j = 0; j < richText.length; j++) {
      var font = richText[j].getTextStyle(); // Get the font style of the rich text run
      if (font.isUnderline()) 
      { // Check if the font style includes underline
         // Change the font color of the underlined text to red
         redColor.setTextStyle(1,2,"red");
         cell.setRichTextValue(redColor);
      }
    }
    cell.setRichTextValue(richTextValue); // Set the modified rich text value back to the cell
  }
}
```

[Dummy Sheet Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c9vBShVK_iyxOelo1Dc0THVRJtP3U0pmiPcxbrLLSJ0/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `getRichTextValue()` and `setRichTextValue()` are used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high.
- From `font.isUnderline()`, in this case, it is checked whether the text style has the underline. In your question, I thought that you wanted to check whether the text style has a strikethrough.
- In your goal, it seems that you wanted to change the font color to "grey" like "#7d7d7d". But, in your script, it seems that `setForegroundColor("#ff0000")` is used. In this case, it's red in color.

If these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function changeUnderlineColor() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Update Strikethroughs");
  var column = ss.getRangeByName("toDos").getColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(3, column, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  var redColor = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("#7d7d7d").setStrikethrough(false).build();
  var richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(([c]) => {
    c.getRuns().forEach(r => {
      if (r.getTextStyle().isStrikethrough()) {
        c = c.copy().setTextStyle(r.getStartIndex(), r.getEndIndex(), redColor).build();
      }
    });
    return [c];
  });
  range.setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run to your provided sample Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- If you want to keep the strikethrough, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      var redColor = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("#7d7d7d").setStrikethrough(false).build();
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var redColor = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("#7d7d7d").build();
    ```

#### References:

- [getRichTextValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalues)
- [setRichTextValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluesvalues)

Comment: Hi Tanaike, This solved the issue. I am not sure if this asking too much but I tried making another version of your script where instead of checking if the text is strikethorugh, check if the text is black, and if it is black, change it to another color. Is this possible? No obligation to respond as I don't want to abuse your kindness. Thank you Tanaike.

Comment: @William Toscano Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `check if the text is black, and if it is black, change it to another color. Is this possible?`, I think that it's yes. For example, how about modifying the above script as follows? From `if (r.getTextStyle().isStrikethrough()) { c = c.copy().setTextStyle(r.getStartIndex(), r.getEndIndex(), redColor).build(); }` to `if (r.getText().length > 0 && r.getTextStyle().getForegroundColor() == "#000000") { c = c.copy().setTextStyle(r.getStartIndex(), r.getEndIndex(), redColor).build(); }`.

Comment: @William Toscano In this case, `redColor` is used as `var redColor = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("#ff0000").build();`. If I misunderstood your additional question, I apologize.

Comment: William, I based my (painfully unsuccessful) development on an approach like that :). But I was always conscious that I was working with just two runs (one: strikethrough, and one: non-strikethrough) yet, in the "real world", how one could predict how many runs there might be, what the split might be, what the order of the runs might be, and what the existing color scheme might be?

Comment: FWIW, I found used the excellent answer in [Formatting Text in the googlesheet cell using a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60125076/1330560) to inform my approach to development on this topic - given a few more weeks, I'm sure that I could have developed an answer to this question :) But, @Tanaike, may I ask for my own education... in the line `var richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(([c]) => {` and following lines, what does `c` represent?

Comment: @Tedinoz About `c` of `var richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(([c]) => {`, in this case, each 1st element of an array from a 2-dimensional array `range.getRichTextValues()` by the destructuring assignment. For example, when `const value = [["a1"], ["a2"],,,]`, `c` of `value.map(([c) => {,,,})` is "a1", "a2",,,.

Comment: @Tedinoz As additional information, when I measured the process cost of retrieving values from arrays with Google Apps Script, the process cost of the destructuring assignment was the lowest of all. [Ref](https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/10/23/benchmark-process-costs-for-retrieving-values-from-arrays-for-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/)

Comment: Argh... Thank you @Tanaike. So, `range.getRichTextValues()` gets an array of "RichTextValues" for each cell; then `getRuns()` ("r") for each "run" within each "c";  test `isStrikethrough()` and go back to "r" to 1) make a copy?? and 2) set a new `TextStyle`. And I just noticed that you `return [c]` - you return an array! I _think_ that I've got all that - a few things that I need to ponder on - (like how you distinguish between two runs in a single cell, and how the respective RichTextValues apply to "c" in that single cell) - a couple of weeks should be enough :)

Comment: @Tanaike "process cost of the destructuring assignment was the lowest " should be on the recommended reading list!!

Comment: @Tedinoz Thank you for replying. If you could get something for yourself from this discussion, I'm glad. Also, `value.map(([c]) => {,,,})` can be also modified to `value.map(r => {const c = r[0],,,})`. But, from the result of process cost, I often use destructuring assignments because of the maximum execution time of Google Apps Script is 6 minutes for most users. About the useful information, I have also published them in Champion Innovators Content Library. [Ref](https://cloud.google.com/innovators/champions/content#/?q=tanaike) If these are useful for you and other users, I'm glad.

Comment: Argh... yet another resource that I didn't know existed. Thanks you, @Tanaike.